# плагин Search & Filter pro wordpress счетчик найденных результатов

Tags: wordpress, ajax, wordpress-плагины

Я использую плагин Search & Filter Pro для поиска новостей по сайту и соответственно фильтров. Все это работает с ajax. Мне нужно чтобы при использовании фильтра или вводе в поле input работал счетчик количества найденных новостей [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу разобраться как мне это реализовать с данным плагином.

В самом плагине есть чекбокс который я так понимаю и должен справляться с данной задачей.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] но я не пойму как его инициализировать. В документации по плагину не нашел информации.. Может кто-то сталкивался ? буду очень благодарен если кто-то подскажет где копать, чтобы разобраться )

Answer (score 0):

Вообще не туда копал. Все намного проще на странице поиска где выводятся Ваши записи добавляете:`<?php  global $wp_query; echo $wp_query->found_posts.' results found.'; ?>`